# Python: error check failing to catch exception

Tags: python, micropython

I'm writing in a stripped down version of python, micro python.
I'm doing some image processing and am trying to find the longest line returned from a method called, "find_line_segments" (it does Canny Edge and Hough Lines transforms).
BUT! I keep getting an error.
Code

```
    rl = max(img.find_line_segments(roi = r_r, threshold = 1000, theta_margin = 15, rho_margin = 15, segment_threshold = 100), key = lambda x: x.length())
    if rl is not None:
        if rl[6] > 0 :
            img.draw_line(rl.line(), color = 155)
            print("RL")
            print(rl)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 77, in <module>
ValueError: arg is an empty sequence
MicroPython d23b594 on 2017-07-05; OPENMV3 with STM32F765
Type "help()" for more information.
```

That error points to the line `if rl is not None:` ... and I don't understand why it is causing an error. If the max() function doesn't return a value (in the case that a line isn't found), the "if statement" should never execute.
What am I not understanding?

Edit:
Accidentally removed some code.

Comment: If you formatted your code correctly it would be easier to help you.

Comment: what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `None != []`. `if rl:` might work since it will avoid anything falsey, but it's a guess because it's hard to understand your question. Also, you don't appear to make any attempt to catch the exception (which your question title suggests) but try to avoid the exceptional circumstance.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right line? It sounds like an error thrown for the max function... Try commenting out everything after the max function and see if it runs.

Comment: @LeopoldVonBuschLight I think what's happening is that the OP thinks that `if rl is not None:` will avoid an exception further down the code, but it's not very clear. It would be helpful if there was a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @roganjosh : i'd love to provide that ... except that you'd need an OpenMV camera (https://openmv.io/) to be able to verify the code in its entirety.

Comment: At the very least, please provide the full traceback (copy/paste the whole thing, not just a bit from the end). Also, please provide feedback on whether changing `if rl is not None:` to `if rl:` made any difference.

Comment: @LeopoldVonBuschLight : I've tried that ... and it does continue to fail ... but what's weird is that this same code sequence has worked elsewhere without issue. Which is why I'm lost.

Comment: @roganjosh : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 77, in <module>
ValueError: arg is an empty sequence
MicroPython d23b594 on 2017-07-05; OPENMV3 with STM32F765
Type "help()" for more information.

Comment: As an edit to the question. Also, your line numbers have changed from 59 to 77. But the traceback should go further back and point to all the lines of code that eventually led to the error as a chain reaction, it's helpful to see it all.

Comment: the rest is just commented code ...

Comment: @slow_one Try seperating out that max(img.find_line_segments(...)...) statement into two statements and test if the result of find_line_segments is anything before using the max function. It sounds like the max function is what's throwing the exception.

Comment: @LeopoldVonBuschLight : I think you're right. I think I'll need to do that ... will be doing so tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating out that `max(img.find_line_segments(...)...)` statement into two statements and test if the result of `find_line_segments` is anything before using the `max` function. It sounds like the `max` function is what's throwing the exception:

```
# Dummy function
def find_line_segments():
    return []

max_segment = max(find_line_segments())
```

Gives this exception for trying to use `max()` on an empty sequence:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayb\Desktop\t (3).py", line 8, in <module>
    max_segment = max(get_line_segments())
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Do something like this instead to avoid the exception.

```
segments = find_line_segments()
if segments:
    max_segment = max(segments)
```

Comment: That if statement seems to have averted the issue. I'm not sure why the max() statement is having that issue. I'll have to explore that further (the find_line_segments() function *is* able to find lines ... it's not that it doesn't having anything to "max()"